# Как остановить обработку onclick после нажатия?

Tags: javascript, html, события

Я решил реализовать свои собственные крестики-нолики, но столкнулся с одной проблемой. Предположим Игрок 1 поставил крестик в центр поля. Тогда Игрок 2 по правилам должен поставить нолик на любое другое поле, кроме центрального. Но в моем недоделанном коде получается так, что Игрок 2 может поставить нолик на то место, где уже стоит крестик. Как исправить сию проблему?

Полями являются div-ы
На каждом div-е висит обработчик события 'click'

Comment: 1) Отписаться от клика. 2) Ничего не делать по клику

Comment: Хранить матрицу полей с флагами использования каждого поля и проверять флаг использования при клике.

Comment: Спасибо большое всем, мне помогло с флагами)